# F-Spaced pickups

Tags: electric-guitar, pick-ups

I want to buy a Dimarzio DP224 pickup which comes in two types : F-Spaced and regular.
I heard that the difference is in the distance between the poles in the pickup.

I have an Ibanez GRG140 guitar and was wondering how can I know if I need a F-Spaced pickup or a regular one ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From DiMarzio's own specs, F-spaced pickups measure 2.01" (51 mm) centre-to-centre from the first polepiece to the sixth. Standard-spaced pickups measure 1.90" (48 mm).

So measure the distance from your first to sixth string at the point the pickup will be installed and choose accordingly.